# UIView animation and transform cause a weird position offset

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiview, cgaffinetransformscale

http://childhoodgamedev.qiniudn.com/xincheng_testGif.gif

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 250, 200, 100)];
label.text = @"Hello world!";
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
[self.view addSubview:label];

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
label.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 2, 2);

[UIView animateWithDuration:4.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
    label.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(label.transform, -100, 0);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {
        NSLog(@"label %f %f %f %f", label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.origin.y, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
            NSLog(@"label %f %f %f %f", label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.origin.y, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);

            label.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(label.transform, 100, 0);
        } completion:NULL];
    }
}];
```

There is `UILabel` instance named `label`, it's scaled to 2 ratio by `CGAffineTransformScale`. Then it moves from right to left, when the animation is completed, then it moves from left to right.

But the strange point is: It looks not the same position, which is the end point of animation(right to left), the start point of animation(left to right). But the NSLog tells me, they are in the same position.

http://childhoodgamedev.qiniudn.com/xincheng_QQ20150306-1.png

When I comment the state `label.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 2, 2);`, everything is fine. When the label change direction to move, the end position of right->left animation is just the start position of left->right animation.

So I think the problem is caused by `CGAffineTransformScale`. Any ideas?